# how can i use bbp_get_reply_author_role()? (Wordpress/bbpress)

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

Can't figure out how to use bbp_get_reply_author_role(), and i really need it, returns an error on trying to echo it, and i can't find any documentation for bbpress template tags like this =/ any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this may help you out @Dactyllo http://bbpress.svn.wordpress.org/branches/plugin/bbp-includes/bbp-reply-template.php

Comment: sure helps, even tho this documentation is far more complicated than the one from codex.wordpress.com x) oh well..... i ended up getting the bbp_get_reply_author_id() and getting the role with the wordpress API, since BBpress users are wordpress users...... thank you tho =)